# how to use FormBuilder in GWT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

I want to create Form generator based on FormBuilder GWT framework.Can someone help me how to use formbuilder in gwt?
i don't find any example.
thanks for helping

Comment: What is FormBuilder? Do you have a link?

Comment: I only find javadoc for FormBuilder:                                                                                    [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/builder/shared/FormBuilder.html)

Comment: Oh, **that** FormBuilder! That I'm afraid I don't understand your question.